# who am I - JQuery, Plugin, $this, $(this), this, access to variable

Tags: jquery, plugins, this

I have a problem with identify the object that runs the function

```
<div id="test1">lorem</div>
<div id="test2">ipsum</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test1').plugin(); //alert: I am test1
        $('#test2').plugin(); //alert: I am test2

        $('#test1').plugin.fun(); //alert: I am undefined and I am undefined
        $('#test2').plugin.fun(); //alert: I am undefined and I am undefined
    });
    (function($) {
        $.fn.plugin = function() {
            $this = $(this);
            alert('I am '+$(this).attr('id'));//<-- it works
        }
        $.fn.plugin.fun = function() {
            alert('I am '+$(this).attr('id')); //<-- doesn't work!
            alert('and I am '+$this.attr('id')); //<-- also doesn't work!
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fun` function doesn't have any direct relation to the object that you are using in the call, so `this` will just be the `window` object.

When you are using `$('#test1').plugin`, you get a reference to that function, and from that you access the function `fun`, but what you get is simply a regular function. You could just as well use `$.fn.plugin.fun` to get to the function, the use of the jQuery object with the selector has no relevance at all once you have got the reference to the `fun` function.

The jQuery object will actually be discarded before the `fun` function is called, so it's impossible to reach it from the function.

Comment: *"The `fun` function doesn't have any direct relation to the object that you are using in the call, so this will just be the `window` object."* No, it'll be the `plugin` function object, because he's calling `fun` via a property on `plugin`. Not that that's more helpful, it still doesn't get him the jQuery instance. (Hadn't seen this answer before; someone just upvoted my answer, which made me wonder what the question was and come look again.)

Answer (score 5):

To understand what `$('#test1').plugin.fun();` is doing, we have to look at how `this` is set within JavaScript functions. We'll start with theory, then come back to your plug-in.

In JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*. The most common way is to set it as a by-product of calling the function from an object property:

```
var foo = {
    msg: "I'm foo!",
    bar: function() {
        alert(this.msg);
    }
};
foo.bar(); // alerts "I'm foo!"
```

That line `foo.bar();` does three distinct things:

1. It retrieves the `bar` property from the `foo` object.
2. It calls the function that property references.
3. It does #2 in such a way that `this` refers to `foo`.

(More here: [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html).)

So in the call

```
$('#test1').plugin.fun();
```

...`this` within `fun` will be `plugin`, because we're calling `fun` via a property on `plugin`.

You might consider using the mechanims used by jQuery UI, which is to have "methods" of the plug-in accessible via a main function, with the names as strings. For instance, on a jQuery UI `Draggable` instance, you can call methods like this:

```
$('#test1').draggable('disable');
```

See their [`Draggable` documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) for more examples, but basically your calls would look like this:

```
$('#test1').plugin('fun');
```

---

More about function calls:

There's another way to set `this` when calling a function: Through the `call` and `apply` functions on the function instance:

```
var f = function() {
    alert(this.msg);
};
var foo = {
    msg: "I'm foo!"
};
f.call(foo);  // alerts "I'm foo!"
f.apply(foo); // alerts "I'm foo!" too
```

`call` and `apply` call a function, setting the `this` value to the first argument you pass into them. The difference between `call` and `apply` is how you pass arguments to the target function. With `call`, you just add further arguments to the `call` function; with `apply`, you give an array of arguments as the second argument to `apply`. Examples:

```
function f(arg1, arg2) {
    alert(this.msg + " (" + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + ")");
}
var foo = {
    msg: "I'm foo!";
};
f.call(foo, "one", "two");    // Alerts "I'm foo! (one, two)"
//          ^-- "one" and "two" are discrete arguments
f.apply(foo, ["one", "two"]); // Alerts the same thing
//           ^------------^-- "one" and "two" are in an array
```

Comment: thnk you T.J. It was useful - I have made my plugin in different way that I was thinking I will at the beginning. JavaScript is not so OO as I'd like it to be

Comment: @Errold: No worries, glad that helped. *"JavaScript is not so OO as I'd like it to be"* JavaScript is very OO -- just not the same OO as some of us got used to with class-based languages. :-)